# Getting actual height of an auto-heighted element in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm pretty confused! with this:

```
...
<div id="main">         
    <div id="content">
        <div class="col1">
        ...COLUMN1 CONTENT GOES HERE...
        </div>

        <div class="col2">
        ...COLUMN2 CONTENT GOES HERE...
        </div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #main -->
...
```

there are columns as you see, and I want to set their container element's height to the maximum size of both columns(plus 130px). so by using Prototype framework:

```
//fixing column height problem
Event.observe(window,"load",function(){             
    if(parseInt($('col1').getStyle('height')) > parseInt($('col2').getStyle('height')))
        $('main').setStyle({'height' : parseInt($('col1').getStyle('height'))+130+'px'});
    else
        $('main').setStyle({'height' : parseInt($('col2').getStyle('height'))+130+'px'});
});//observe
```

It working nice in Firefox, Opera, Safari & Chrome but it fails to return the actual height of columns. in IE7+ (not tested in IE6) it returns **NaN** as columns height.
I've managed to find out that's because of this:

```
.col1,.col2{"height:auto;"}
```

I've also used "$('col1').offsetHeight" and it's returning 0 as the height value of each column.

the HTML is styled in this way:

```
#main{
height: 455px;
background: #484848 url(../images/mainbg.png) repeat-x;
}
#content{
/*height:80%;*/
width: 960px;
direction: rtl;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
}
.col1,.col2{
width: 33%;
text-align: right;
margin-left:3px;
padding-right:3px;
line-height:17px;
}
.col1{padding-top:20px;}
.col1 ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style: url(../images/listBullet.gif);
}
.col1 ul li{
margin-bottom:20px;
}
.col2{
top: 0;
right: 70%;
position: absolute;
}
```

any idea on the issue please?!

**update**/ It tooks three days to solve, and I was at the very risk of making a bounty!
for the solution please take a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697271/javascript-event-hierarchy-in-prototype-framework).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a completion for Marc's answer; There's an equal for jQuery's *height()* in Prototype:

```
$('col1').getDimensions().height //or .width ofcourse
```

And here's the docs: http://prototypejs.org/api/element/getDimensions

**Update:** I agree with [crescentfresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692523/getting-actual-height-of-an-auto-heighted-element-in-ie/692670#692670) below. Since I had the absolute same problem in the past, I've searched all possible methods to find the dimension properties but I failed as you will. please take a look at this:

```
function getStyle(oElm, strCssRule){
    var strValue = "";
    if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){
        strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oElm, "").getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
    }
    else if(oElm.currentStyle){
        strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1){
            return p1.toUpperCase();
        });
        strValue = oElm.currentStyle[strCssRule];
    }
    return strValue;
}
```

As you see, the function [has been written](http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/) to get the *computed rendered current style of an element*, but in our case even this method will fail, I guess. (worth a try)

So, as crescentfresh [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692523/getting-actual-height-of-an-auto-heighted-element-in-ie/692670#692670), you have to find the problem in your CSS positioning method while not wasting your time seeking for a proper javascript function which could be able to do the magic. let's begin by removing that *#content* DIV and letting the *#main* to be the only wrapper of said columns, and then styling the remain to achieve the desired goal.

Comment: thank you both, but it's not working!!! returning 0 as before. I'm extremely weired through this -_-

Comment: I'm absolutely confused but I really appreciate the help. many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Since IE wants to give you a hard time, you can give it some special attention and use a property that I believe it will recognize...

```
var height;
if(document.all) { //This means it is IE
  height = document.getElementById('col1').offsetHeight;
}
else {
  height = //Use what is working in other browsers now
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, the offsetHeight() is not working and I've mentioned that in the question body, thanks ;)

Comment: I seen what you mentioned in the question body.  But you are using the $() function instead of the native getElementById(), and I am not exactly sure what that returns.

Answer (score 1):

From:
[Why would jquery return 0 for an offsetHeight when firebug says it's 34?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636474/why-would-jquery-return-0-for-an-offsetheight-when-firebug-says-its-34)

> An element that is not actually taking
>   part in the document render process
>   has no dimensions, and will give an
>   offsetWidth/Height of 0.

Both Prototype's `getDimensions()` and jQuery's `height()` read the `offsetHeight` or `clientHeight` properties, which you've tried and got 0. So somewhere in your code there must be *something* taking `#col` out of the rendering flow. That's all I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Artarad,
The above style i.e. css shows that you have not assigned height.
Please try adding _height:auto in class which will look like

```
    .col1,.col2{
width: 33%;
_height:auto;
height:auto;
text-align: right;
margin-left:3px;
padding-right:3px;
line-height:17px;
}
```

Basically, many browsers fail to recognize the height when assigned to a particular div or any element . In this case we use the above work arounds.
I hope the above helps you.

Thanks,
Samiksha

Comment: many thanks Samiksha, but It's not working for me. Additionally I removed the 80% height rule and it's keep failing :( actually what this underline character shall be able to do?

Comment: The underscore used before any attribute signifies that it applies to ie7 browser only. I apologize for this solution not helped you.. will let you know definitely if i find a way...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work (without testing), but you could try jQuery and [height()](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height); this (in theory) gives the computed height. Worth a try...

Comment: thanks Marc, but I'm using prototype and I think that won't be nice to use both of 'em on a single page, ain't it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I found a better answer than "Fix the css and forget the javascript".

I had the exast same problem and used `.innerHeight()` and it forced jQuery to calculate the height. For some reason `.outerHeight()` did not work whilst `.innerHeight()` solved the problem. Not sure if there is a similar method for prototype. You could look into the jQuery library and figure out how `.innerHeight()` works, and write your own.