# Javascript Event Hierarchy in Prototype framework

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, event-handling, prototypejs

is there any event to be handled between the *dom:loaded* and *load* using Prototype javascript framework?
I've implemented a preloader using prototype which is looking like this:

```
Event.observe(window,"load",preload);
function preload(){
    if($('wrapper'))
        $('wrapper').setStyle({"display":"block"});
    if($('loading'))
        setTimeout('$("loading").fade({duration: 5.0});',4000);
}
```

then I've an another handler using for column height fixatioan which is:

```
Event.observe(window,"load",function(){ 
    var bottomExtraOffset = (Prototype.Browser.IE) ? 100 : 130;
    if(parseInt($$('.col1')[0].getStyle('height')) > parseInt($$('.col2')[0].getStyle('height')))
        $('wrapper').setStyle({'height' : parseInt($$('.col1')[0].getStyle('height'))+bottomExtraOffset+'px'}); 
    else
        $('wrapper').setStyle({'height' : parseInt($$('.col2')[0].getStyle('height'))+bottomExtraOffset+'px'});
});//observe
```

It's working pretty nice in any browser but IE! It seems that IE is not appending the second handler to the onload handlers list, so when the first one is trying to get height of any of columns it returns 0 coz it's still displayed as none.

is there any other event than *load* & *dom:loaded* to be handled and get me outta this!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such event AFAIK, and even the *dom:loaded* event is implemented by Prototype developers and that's not a default event in JS. You might want to use a helper to make a delay in performing of the second handler, so the first one will be performed first:

```
function foo(){ 
    var bottomExtraOffset = (Prototype.Browser.IE) ? 100 : 130;
    if (parseInt($$('.col1')[0].getStyle('height')) > parseInt($$('.col2')[0].getStyle('height'))) {
        $('wrapper').setStyle({'height' : parseInt($$('.col1')[0].getStyle('height')) + bottomExtraOffset + 'px'}); 
    }
    else {
        $('wrapper').setStyle({'height' : parseInt($$('.col2')[0].getStyle('height')) + bottomExtraOffset + 'px'});
    }
}

function bar() {
  // One msec delay.
  setTimeout(foo, 1);
}

Event.observe(window, "load", bar); // or window.observe("load",bar);
```

Also, you can check if the user agent is some hell like IE, then use this method and your said one otherwise.

Comment: wow! many thanks, it's working like a charm ^o^ you know, you've just answered my previous question which we've discussed before with no such a solution, it tooks 3 days to find the problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply call the second function after you've finished preload() ?

Or if you dont want to directly call it after preload() then you could do something like set a flag and then set a timeout in the section function to wait until the first is done to execute.

If order is important you need to communicate between the functions.

Comment: I can't directly call the second after the first one due to the whole script algorithm. I'm workin' on your suggestion, thanks Ryan.